# How to make softbody interact with an animated rigid body

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body, rigidbody

I am trying to make a scene where a softbody cube falls into a long spinning rectangular rigid mesh, but it turns out that both doesn't interact with each other as the cube just falls through and ignores the movement of the animated mesh.

I know for a fact that softbody can interact with rigid body because the softbody cube falls into a plane that has a rigid body property, but apparently it doesn't work when the rigid body has animation.

I looked up on YouTube for this but found nothing.

Comment: You "know for a fact" that soft bodies can interact with rigid bodies? Yes, they can - but not by default, only if the rigid body object has a _Collision_ modifier. And then it works no matter if animated or not, as the answer from @Chris shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give your rigid body a collision modifier, and it works:

[image]

Comment: I literally asked openai how to add collision modifier to a rigid body, thanks for the info anyways

Comment: @KD_ Well, as Ray commented on a different question a few days ago: _"First - I would strongly recommend against using ChatGPT as a general knowledge engine. It has frequently been shown to provide confident, totally incorrect answers."_ ChatGPT had given (-3, -3, 3) as the dot product of (3, 0, 0) and (0, 0, 1), which is utter nonsense.